# MySQL Table Value Parameter?

Tags: mysql, table-valued-parameters

I come from Microsoft SQL Server - but am converting a database to MySQL.  I have this syntax which works excellent on my MSSQL install

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableValue_ExceptionsTable] AS TABLE(
[TN] [varchar](31) NOT NULL,
`PF` [varchar](255) NULL,
`ET` [varchar](255) NULL,
`S1` `datetime` NULL,
`S2` `datetime` NULL,
`S3` `datetime` NULL,
`S4` [varchar](35) NULL,
`S5` [varchar](35) NULL,
`S6` [varchar](35) NULL
```

)

What is the equivelant of this in MySQL?

Comment: MySQL has no TABLE type or user-defined type. I think You can use JSON instead.

Comment: See if MySQL's Workbench will decipher it all.